# How to execute an exe using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, scripting

I have an exe, which takes 2 .csv files as input. As below:

```
cSplittinglines.exe srcdir\file.csv destdir\file.csv
```

How can I execute this .exe using a shell script so that the directory from which the script is run has no impact on the location of the exe. aka avoid hard coding the exe path. Below is the script I am working on.

```
#!/bin/sh
STARTTIME=`date '+%Y%m%d.%H%M%S'`

LOGFILE=${ERRDIR}/${0}.${STARTTIME}

SplitDir=$1

LyxlamDir=$2

echolog ()
{
    echo $*
    echo $* >> ${LOGFILE}
}

    for file in "${SplitDir}"/*; do
    if [ -d "$file" ]; then continue; fi
    extension=${file##*.}

    if [ "$extension" = "csv" ]
    then    
        cSplittingLines.exe "$file" "${LyxlamDir}"
        mv "$file" "${SplitDir}/old"

    fi
done
```

Comment: You seem to have a strange mix of Windows executable and paths and Unix shell script. What is the context you're working in for that to happen?

Comment: yes,its a windows exe.  We always use shell script for windows exe,which works fine,so as to pass the parameters for the exe. We have a MKS tool which also takes shell script in windows.

Comment: That's *probably* a relevant element for you to include in the question, and anything else about the environment that might help someone to answer.

Comment: What is going wrong? Show us (in the question). “Something goes wrong some where”, is not useful, and will not help us spot an error.

Comment: Try adding an `echo about to run  cSplittingLines.exe` to the script, that way you can see if it gets to this bit of the script. Alternatively turn on shell tracing.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the exe on your $PATH (That is what it is for) (%PATH% on Windows)

```
mv cSplittingLines.exe /bin/
```

or

```
echo "export PATH=\"\$PATH:/path/to/exe\"" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Also https://www.shellcheck.net said;

```
SC2006: Use $(...) notation instead of legacy backticked `...`.
SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
```

Comment: Or specify directory and name, in script.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I assume by " I don't want it as hard coded" he ment he did not want that. Maybe he will clarify.

Comment: ya.. the directory and file path should not be hard coded.

Comment: What about `"$(dirname $0)/…/cSplittingLines.exe"` replace the … with the relative path.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yah any relative path would work if the 2 were kept relative to eachother but the ambiguity of the question led me to the more robust solution.